# $\sqrt{2 KL(f || g)}$ interpretation?

Tags: distributions, interpretation, distance, kullback-leibler, divergence

I have seen in some papers that instead of using the Kullback-Leibler divergence $KL(f || g)$ between two probability density functions, $f$ and $g$, they use

$$\sqrt{2 KL(f || g)}.$$

Is there any motivation for this specific transformation?

Comment: I suspect the papers are using Jensen–Shannon distance, but that is a function of *symmetric* KL divergence rather than the asymetric KL divergence in your expression.

Comment: @GordonSmyth They use the KL divergence rather than the JS distance (for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4630.pdf).

Comment: The paper explains the motivation for using the measure they do. Why are you not satisfied with their motivation?

Comment: @GordonSmyth They do not really say why. "will use the (unidirectional) measure" is not really an explanation.

Comment: There is quite a bit more explanation than what you quote. In any case, this distance measure appears to have been proposed in the paper you are reading and is not widely used elsewhere, so the paper itself will be the best explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in [the paper you reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4630.pdf). In section 3.1:

> Here, the factor “2” is introduced for convenience and the square root deals with the power of two that is naturally associated with the KLD (see the simple example at the end of this subsection).

Look at A2 page 36, and then section 4.1, page 16 *Behaviour near the base model* where there is an expansion of the KL divergence showing the quadratic behaviour for small distance (there $\xi$).